# SSRS show ERROR Forward dependencies are not valid

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

In my query for Dataset I have

```
SELECT
    App_Ministries.Ministry_Code,
    App_Ministries.App_Code
FROM
    App_Ministries
WHERE  
    (App_Code IN (@prmApp_code)) AND (App_Code <> 'fax')
```

For my Aprameters Setting, I have

[image]

And I tried to create a table with `App_code` like this :

[image]

But When I tried to Preview it I got this ERROR

[image]
I am Not sure why Help, please

Update!
I'm just trying to display App_code that select by Parameters
For example, I have a table for appcode
[image]

and I want the report only to display the App_code that I have select here:

[image]

Comment: You are trying to populate a list of parameter options from a dataset query, but the dataset query relies on the parameter value you are setting so it's a circular reference. You should probably explain what you are trying to do, with examples of data and required output and we can offer more guidance.

Comment: Hi, @AlanSchofield  I'm trying to display only the App_code that selected from the Parameters "prmApp_code".

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield I have updated on sample data and what I trying to do.

Comment: You can use a separate dataset to populate your parameter and your main dataset should be filtered based on your selection.